# How do I reference a .dll for many processor architectures?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, reference

I have a project that creates a .dll and a windows runtime component. I want to reference it in my main project so when I build a x86, the x86 .dll is referenced AND when I build x64 , the x64 .dll is referenced AND when I build ARM, the ARM .dll is referenced.

Right now I build x64 then build ARM and I get things along the lines of

*There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "ARM" and the processor architecture, "AMD64", of the implementation file This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and implementation file, or choose a winmd file with an implementation file that has a processor architecture which matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.*

I understand why I am getting this error (I am referencing a x64 .dll when it tries to build ARM). I don't understand how to make the reference change if the processor changes. I feel like this would be a build step, but I don't know anything about build steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the output directory of the .dll to the same folder no matter the configuration, so each time I build, the reference gets overridden to the right build configuration.